# python pandas: pivot rows to columns based on duplicate index columns

Tags: python, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with repeated column values as shown below

```
id,  key, qual, metric, value

abc  xyz  TRK    a      5528
abc  xyz  TRK    b      1234
abc  xyz  TRK    c      Error
abc  xyz  TRK    d      OK
```

I need the output as given below

```
id   key  qual  a     b     c     d

abc  xyz  TRK   5528  1234  Error  OK
```

I have tried using pivot but the result was dropping key and qual columns.

```
measures = measures.pivot(index='id',columns='metric',values='value')
```

Comment: I had to actually modify the layout. The value column would also contain text values

Answer (score 1):

You can use some dataframe reshaping...   However, I am a bit confuse by your values of b, c, and d in your expected output.

Try this using `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(df.columns[:-1].tolist())['value'].unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    id  key qual     a     b     c     d
0  abc  xyz  TRK  5528  1234  3453  4544
```

Another way is to use `pivot_table`(will *not* work with string in value column):

```
df.pivot_table(columns='metric',index=['id','key','qual'])['value']
```